# AWS Connect, adding first phone number error. "You've reached the limit of Phone Numbers. To increase limit, contact support. "

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to set up an inbound call center with AWS connect. It should be straight forward, but when I try to claim my first phone number and hit save, it says:

"You've reached the limit of Phone Numbers. To increase limit, contact support.". The default for AWS Connect says I should be able to have 5 phone numbers, so why is it preventing me from making 1?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. I had zero number claimed and still getting the error "**You've reached the limit of Phone Numbers. To increase limit, contact support.**". My Connect instance was provisioned long ago in POC account and I had not been using this instance for some months now.

After contacting AWS Support, they increased the "**Phone numbers per instance**" limit from default 5 to 6 and soon after I was able to claim my first number.

I don't have RCA for the issue but limit increase fixed it for me.